# Merging mp4 files with different resolutions using ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy, pyffmpeg

Hi I'm trying to concat/merge mp4 files in a directory using this command below:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i 1.mp4 -i 10.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=1[v0]; [1:v]scale=1024:576:force_original_aspect_ratio=1[v1]; [v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] output.mp4
```

But I'm Getting this error:

```
[Parsed_concat_2 @ 0000017ff3e1c880] Input link in0:v0 parameters (size 1024x576, SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (412x576, SAR 41472:41509)
[Parsed_concat_2 @ 0000017ff3e1c880] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_2
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
Conversion failed!
```

Can Anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: According to the error message: *(size 1024x576, SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (412x576, SAR 41472:41509)*, it looks like you can't use `force_original_aspect_ratio=1`. The standard solution is `[0:v]scale=1024:576,setsar=1[v0]`. Try the following command: `ffmpeg.exe -i 1.mp4 -i 10.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1024:576,setsar=1[v0];[1:v]scale=1024:576,setsar=1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map [v] -map [a] output.mp4`